# How to make "duck" audio effect in real time (pyaudio)

Tags: python, pyaudio, voice, librosa, pitch-shifting

Idea: Read the user's microphone and in real time (possible delay up to 500ms) change the pitch of the audio and play it to the output device (Virtual Audio Cable).

```py
from librosa.effects import pitch_shift
...
def pitch_shift_callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    pitch_value = 6
    audio_data = np.frombuffer(in_data, dtype=np.float32)
    shifted_audio_data = pitch_shift(audio_data, sr=44100, n_steps=pitch_value)
    out_data = shifted_audio_data.tobytes()
    return (out_data, pyaudio.paContinue)

...
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32, channels=1, rate=44100,
        input_device_index=SETTINGS["INPUT_DEVICE"],
        output_device_index=SETTINGS["OUTPUT_DEVICE"],
        input=True, output=True,
        stream_callback=pitch_shift_callback,
        frames_per_buffer=2048)
```

I have a fairly powerful computer, but when processing, I get a choppy effect between chunks.

I tried increasing and decreasing the size of the chunks, but it does not help.

I also researched why this happens. If you leave the raw audio (don't resample it) and just set `time.sleep(0.05)`, then this choppy effect will also appear.

```py
def pitch_shift_callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    time.sleep(0.01)
    return (in_data, pyaudio.paContinue)
```

Does anyone know how this can be fixed? Help please.